# obtaining an enum value

Tags: c#, .net, enums, typeof

```
public enum TimeOfDay
    {
        Morning = 0,
        Afternoon = 1,
        Evening = 2
    }
```

Question: When we want to obtain an enum value from its string, we can use:

```
TimeOfDay time = TimeOfDay.Afternoon;
Console.WriteLine((int)time);
```

But what does maen the code below (with the same answer)?

```
TimeOfDay time2 = (TimeOfDay) Enum.Parse(typeof(TimeOfDay), "afternoon", true);
Console.WriteLine((int)time2);
```

Thank you,
Mohsen

Comment: Looks like .NET - is this c#? Please add a suitable language tag to your question.

Comment: @athabaska This is a perfectly valid question. Please moderate your responses

Comment: Thank you, shree.pat18. The best programmers are very polite people.

Comment: @user2987231 That shouldn't be limited to programmers alone. That said, though, please go through the FAQ to ensure that you post on-topic questions in the future as well.

Comment: Apologies for rudeness, but seriously - googling "Enum.Parse" is even easier than making topic here.

Comment: @athabaska I agree with you on your point, but sometimes it is difficult to get a clear idea from MSDN documentation.

Answer (score 3):

MSDN defines the Enum.Parse method as

> Converts the string representation of the name or numeric value of one
>   or more enumerated constants to an equivalent enumerated object.

That is, the method takes either the integer or string representation and returns corresponding object from the associated Enum. In this case, user supplies the string parameter "afternoon", Enum type "TimeOfDay" and sets the case insensitive flag to true. The method then does case-insensitive match against the objects in the Enum and returns the object which has name matching the user's parameter.